# Primefaces menuitem onclick

Tags: primefaces, menuitem, primefaces-extensions

I have using a menuitem from the prime faces, I want in log file that the user clicked on this menu item.

This function does not really work when I click on the menu item. 
I put javacscript code alert('smt'), it does work, but it does not call this function. 
I tried the same function with the 
p:remotecommand 
it does work

Comment: I would be much easier if you could provide some examples that works and that doesn't work for you...

Comment: In this example it does not work: 
<composite:implementation>
    <p:tabMenu id="main-tab-view" activeIndex="#{cc.attrs.activeIndex}">
        <p:menuitem value="#{msg['navigation.configuration.user']}" outcome="/configuration/user.xhtml" icon="tab-icon stoll-icon-konfiguration-2" onclick="#{erpConfigurationBean.ConfigurationMenuItemClicked('write something in the logfile')}"/>
    </p:tabMenu>
</composite:implementation>

Comment: In this example it does work:
<div>
<p:remoteCommand id="removeMachineCommand"                                             name="PPSremoveMachineCommand" update="@form _groups-form_removeMachine"
action="#{groupAssignmentBean.removeSelectedMachinesFromSelectedGroup}"/>
</div>